# AWS Glue Job Takes long during peak hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a Glue Spark ETL Job reading and writing to Postgresql via JDBC, with G.1x worker type. The Job has run time ranging from 3 mins to 13 mins.

It runs quickly during off peak hours, e.g. weekends, whereas on peak hours it takes long.

what could be the reason for this?